# Image not displayed in listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-imageview

Went through many demos and was not able to figure out how to get the imageview work in list view.
Tried the code however the image is not visible in listview. Other details are working fine in the list view
Please help.

Following is the code
The mainactivity has tabhost. Under the second tab listview is present.
listdata is the data that i need in the list.
MyBaseAdapter is for the adapter needed to load data in listview.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.trial;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] dish={"Baby Corn Satay","Dum Aloo","Kadai Paneer","Methi Mutter Malai","Paneer Butter Masala","Saag Panner","Veg Kolhapuri"};
    String[] about={"Baby Corn with marinade in a skewer","Baby Poatatoes in a spicy gravy","Kadhai paneer","Methi and peas in malai","Cottage cheese in butter masala","Cottage cheese in gravy","Spicy veg mix"};
    String[] dprice={"250","300","350","250","350","250","300"};
    Integer[] icon={R.drawable.baby_corn_satay,R.drawable.dum_aloo,R.drawable.kadai_paneer,R.drawable.methi_mutter_malai,R.drawable.paneer_butter_masaala,R.drawable.saag_paneer,R.drawable.veg_kolhapuri};
    ArrayList<ListData> myList=new ArrayList<ListData>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabHost th=(TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs=th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Beverages");
        th.addTab(specs);
         list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            getInList();
                    list.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this,myList));
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +dish[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        specs=th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Cuisines");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs=th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Desserts");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs=th.newTabSpec("tag4");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        specs.setIndicator("Tri");
        th.addTab(specs);






    }
    private void getInList(){

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
        ListData ld=new ListData();
            ld.setAbout(about[i]);
            ld.setDish(dish[i]);
            ld.setDprice(dprice[i]);
            ld.seticon(icon[i]);
            myList.add(ld);
        }

        }


}
```

---

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="Orientation" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="529dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
                        android:text="Tab1"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="Orientation" >



                                        <ListView
                                            android:id="@+id/list"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            tools:ignore="TooDeepLayout" >

                                        </ListView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="Orientation" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="529dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
                        android:text="Tab3"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="Orientation" >
                      <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button44"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="529dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
                        android:text="tab4"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**MyBaseAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.trial;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ListData> myList=new ArrayList<ListData>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ListData> myList){
    this.myList=myList;
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyViewHolder mvh;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dishview,null);
            mvh=new MyViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(mvh);
        }
        else
        {
            mvh=(MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        mvh.dish  = detail (convertView,R.id.dish,myList.get(position).getDish());
        mvh.dprice= detail (convertView,R.id.price,myList.get(position).getDprice());
        mvh.about  = detail (convertView,R.id.about,myList.get(position).getAbout());
        mvh.icon= idetail(convertView,R.id.icon,myList.get(position).geticon());
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
           np.setMaxValue(9);
           np.setMinValue(1);
           np.setValue(1);
          Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
          b.setTag(convertView);
        return convertView;
    }


    private  ImageView idetail(View v,int resId,int icon)
    {
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
    return iv;

    }

    private  TextView detail(View v,int resId,String text)
    {
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(resId);
        tv.setText(text);
        return tv;
    }

    private static class MyViewHolder{
        TextView about,dish,dprice;
        ImageView icon;
    }



}
```

---

**ListData.java**

```
package com.example.trial;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
public class ListData {
    String dish;
    String about;
     String dprice;
     Integer icon;

    public String getDish() {
        return dish;
    }
    public void setDish(String dish) {
        this.dish = dish;
    }
    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }
    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }
    public String getDprice() {
        return dprice;
    }
    public void setDprice(String dprice) {
        this.dprice = dprice;
    }
    public Integer geticon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void seticon(Integer imageId) {
        this.icon = imageId;
    }
}
```

---

**dishview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dish"
        android:text="Discription"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dish"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:text="Dish name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/about"
        android:layout_marginRight="146dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/qty"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="NewApi" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/price"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qty"
        android:text="Add"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Kindly help me out.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: post the complete logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake is in MyBaseAdapter.java
simple mistake, parameters mismatched.
insted of

```
  private  ImageView idetail(View v,int resId,int icon)
    {
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
    return iv;

    }
```

we need to change it to

```
 private  ImageView idetail(View v,int resId,int icon)
    {
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    iv.setImageResource(icon);
    return iv;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just changed position of layout and it stopped working

Clean and rebuild. Likely your resource ids in binary XML files and `R.java` are out of sync.

Now that you've included logcat, `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` in `detail()` are also indicative of this - the resource ids you're passing to the method are valid `TextView`s but at least in one case it is referring to an `ImageView` in binary XML.

Comment: hey.. thanx.. this did it.. however the image and about string not displayed.. could u help

Comment: That's a different question but quickly looking at the layout, seems like you're drawing other views on top of them.

Comment: there is nothing over the area where imageview is there. So no point of overlap

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your activity_main.xml? Moreso, it is preferable you use actionbar tabs.